# Need help for reading gyroscope data

Tags: c, arduino, gyroscope

I'am working with an LSM6DSO32 on an Arduino SAMD21 Cortex M0. So after reading the datasheet I have some interrogation about the raw data. So for the gyroscope I read

[image]

I want to use my gyroscope with `FS = ±500 dps`.
For reading raw data I do that, (page 79 in the datasheet for registers), this code was inspired by [st cource code here](https://github.com/STMicroelectronics/STMems_Standard_C_drivers/blob/master/lsm6dso32_STdC/driver/lsm6dso32_reg.c)

```
Wire.beginTransmission(DSO_ADDRESS); 
Wire.write(0x20);                                      
Wire.endTransmission();   
Wire.requestFrom(DSO_ADDRESS, 14);

static int16_t data_raw_angular_rate[3];
uint8_t buff[14];    
Wire.readBytes(buff, 14);

//some codes here for temperature

//get raw data from gyro
data_raw_angular_rate[0] = (int16_t)buff[1];
data_raw_angular_rate[0] = (val[0] * 256) + (int16_t)buff[0];
data_raw_angular_rate[1] = (int16_t)buff[3];
data_raw_angular_rate[1] = (val[1] * 256) + (int16_t)buff[2];
data_raw_angular_rate[2] = (int16_t)buff[5];
data_raw_angular_rate[2] = (val[2] * 256) + (int16_t)buff[4];

//convert data 17.5 comes from the datasheet for FS = ±500 dps
float_t gyro_x = ((float_t)data_raw_angular_rate[0]) * 17.5f;
float_t gyro_y = ((float_t)data_raw_angular_rate[1]) * 17.5f;
float_t gyro_z = ((float_t)data_raw_angular_rate[2]) * 17.5f;
```

So after this code if I've all understood the datasheet (I'm not sure about that...), After this code, do I get the values ​​in degrees second ? Because the final objective of my code is to used a complementary filter or maybe Kalman fitler and this filter requires gyro value in deg/s

Comment: I do not understand what your question is. I can see a "?" but it does not mark a question as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Yunnosch I'm not sure if after my code, my data are in degrees by second ? I'm not sure about my math after getting raw data

Comment: Again, you use a "?" where I cannot see a question.

Comment: @Clifford ok so I really don't undertand how can I get values in degrees second, should I use time in my math between two measure?

Comment: @simon.  No the value is already in s^-1 units - time is already accounted for.  You would only need to account for time is you were integrating the result to get delta-degrees - even then the time is implicit if you sample at precisely regular intervals.  I am not sure how you are comfortable with the math of Kalman filters yet this is confusing you.

Comment: @Clifford Yes I understand thanks, for the moment I only play with a complimentary filter it's more easy before trying to use Kalman

Comment: regarding `data_raw_angular_rate[0] = (int16_t)buff[1];
data_raw_angular_rate[0] = (val[0] * 256) + (int16_t)buff[0];
data_raw_angular_rate[1] = (int16_t)buff[3];
data_raw_angular_rate[1] = (val[1] * 256) + (int16_t)buff[2];
data_raw_angular_rate[2] = (int16_t)buff[5];
data_raw_angular_rate[2] = (val[2] * 256) + (int16_t)buff[4];`    this is not writing the values, correctly, to the `data-aw_angular_rate[]` array  2)  variable `val[]` is not defined.

Comment: suggest:  `data_raw_angular_rate[0] = (int16_t)(buff[1] << 8);
data_raw_angular_rate[0] += (int16_t)(buff[0] << 8);
data_raw_angular_rate[1] = (int16_t)(buff[3] << 8);
data_raw_angular_rate[1] += (int16_t)buff[2];
data_raw_angular_rate[2] = (int16_t)(buff[5] << 8);
data_raw_angular_rate[2] +=  (int16_t)buff[4];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

G_So is defined in mdps (millidegrees per second).  It means that at ±500 dps a value of 1 corresponds to 0.0175 degrees per second.  So:

```
float_t gyro_x = ((float_t)data_raw_angular_rate[0]) * 0.0175f;
float_t gyro_y = ((float_t)data_raw_angular_rate[1]) * 0.0175f;
float_t gyro_z = ((float_t)data_raw_angular_rate[2]) * 0.0175f;
```

Comment: Ok so just to be sure if I understand everything, when I've done ``float_t gyro_x = ((float_t)data_raw_angular_rate[0]) * 17.5f;``  values were in mdps is it right ?

Comment: Yes.  If you keep everything in mdps you might not need the overhead of floating point.  You could have. `int gyro_x = (data_raw_angular_rate[0]) * 37) / 2 ;`.  To be honest I'd question the need to convert anything at all - your Kalman filter should not need to worry about specific units - all you need perhaps is that 20571 = 360 degrees.